# Явное приведение типов и lexical_cast

Tags: c++, boost

Пример кода:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A
{
    int a;
    explicit operator std::string() {
        return "<" + std::to_string(a) + ">";
    }

};

void f(std::string s) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a {1};
    f(static_cast<std::string>(a));
    f(std::string(a));
    f((std::string)a);
    // f(boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Вопроса 2:

1) Можно ли запретить приведение типов в С-стиле, так, чтобы на вызов `f(std::string(a))` или `f((std::string)a)` компилятор ругался, а `f(static_cast<std::string>(a))` работало?

2) Как "научить" срабатывать вызов `f(boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(a))`?

Comment: Приведение в си-стиле это `(T)var`, а не `T(var)`. Второе называется *function style cast*. По п.1. мне кажется разделить не получится, т.к. в обоих случаях вызывается Ваш оператор преобразования. Т.е. по контексту они эквивалентны. Если только `static_cast` в какой-нибудь макрос не обернуть. Но это так, мысль в полусонном состоянии.

Comment: @alexolut я понимаю, но работает и так и эдак. Добавил в вопросе.

Comment: А может вместо `operator std::string` просто сделаете метод `toString`?

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJlb, увы, по некоторым причинам так не хочется. Оптимально- lexical_cast

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что касается запрета приведения в стиле C, могу только посоветовать посмотреть в сторону опций компилятора. В GCC, например, можно добавить флаги `-Wold-style-cast` и `-Werror`, тогда приведение в стиле C будет вызывать предупреждение, а предупреждения будут трактоваться как ошибки.

С `boost::lexical_cast` все просто, нужно добавить специализацию шаблона. Ваш пример примет такой вид:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

struct A
{
    int a;
    explicit operator std::string() const{
        return "<" + std::to_string(a) + ">";
    }
};

namespace boost{
    template<>
    std::string lexical_cast<std::string, A>(const A& arg){
        return std::string(arg);
    }
};

void f(std::string s) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a {1};
    f(static_cast<std::string>(a));
    f(std::string(a));
    f((std::string)a);
    f(boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(a));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Кстати, `-Wold-style-cast` не дает ворнинга для функционального приведения.

Comment: @alexolut, Как по мне он и не должен. Вообще никогда не понимал почем это называют приведением типа. Это же просто создание анонимного объекта при помощи конструктора с одним параметром.

Comment: Это потому, что конструктор без `explicit` с одним параметром называется преобразующим.

Comment: А не должен по причине того, что это не есть `old-style-cast`. Об этом я упоминал в комментарии к вопросу уже.

Comment: Спасибо, все работает. Сорри за задержку.

Answer (score 2):

Сообразил некое [костыльное решение](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/Tgv0doQkaTn6YAeS) для запрета преобразований без `static_cast`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class T, class X>
T my_cast(X&& x) {
    return static_cast<T>(x);
}

#define static_cast my_cast

struct A
{
    int a;
private:    
    explicit operator std::string() const {
        return "<" + std::to_string(a) + ">";
    }

    template <class T, class X>
    friend T my_cast(X&& x);
};

void f(std::string s) {
    std::cout << s << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    A a {1};
    f(static_cast<std::string>(a)); // ok
    f(std::string(a)); // error
    f((std::string)a); // error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не хочется плодить костыли, но все равно спасибо.